# Website Formatting Troubles

Tags: html, css, format

So I've been trying to work on my website creation skills and was reading various tutorials concerning html/css developing. The problem I now have run into is that when I alter the size of my page the view gets incredibly altered. I was under the assumption that when the view changed it would keep it's structure but have a smaller view window (not the case).

Does the problem lie with me using percent values instead of pixels? Is there a better way to structure my design to make it responsive to window size alterations?

This is my HTML

```
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title> MyWebsite</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="containerColumn1">
    <div id="Fill1"> </div>
</div>

<div id="containerTopLogo">
    <div id="FillTopLogo"> </div>
</div>

<div class="menu-wrap">
 <nav class="menu">
  <ul class="clearfix">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Services <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"> Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Option 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>  

    <li>
        <a href="#"> Services2 <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"> Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Option 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="3"> Site Map</a></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
 </div> 

<div id="containerPicture"> 

    <div id="headerPicture"> </div>
</div>

<div id="container"> 
    <div id="header"> </div>
</div>  

<div id="containerColumn2">
    <div id="Fill2"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my style.css

```
body {
    background: #FFFFFF url('body-bg.jpg');
}

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}


/*COLUMNS TO CENTER PAGE*/

#containerColumn1 {
    width:18.2%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px groove #000;
}

#Fill1 {
    background: red;
    height:100%;
}

#containerTopLogo {
    width:61.3%;
    margin-left:18.4%;
    margin-top:-47.4%;
    height:23%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px groove #000;

}

#FillTopLogo {
    background: green;
    height:100%;
}

#containerColumn2 {
    width:18%;
    margin-top: -49.82%;
    margin-left: 80%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px groove #000;
}

#Fill2 {
    background: red;
    height:100%;
}


/*Menu Outline*/


.menu-wrap {
    width:50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#000000;
}

/* Height of menu (Home)(*MARGIN*) AND LEFT-RIGHT PLACEMENT(*WIDTH*)*/
.menu {
    width: 61.5%;
    margin:0%;
    position: absolute;
    left:19%;
    top: 25%;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #000000;

}

.menu li{
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#000000;
}

.menu li a:hover > a .menu .current-item a{
    color:#FFF000;
}


.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}


/* Top of the Page */

.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

/* Menu Item spacing (Vertical/Horizontal) */
.menu > ul > li > a  {
    /* Menu Spacing Vert/Hor */
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a{
    background:#FFFFFF;
}



/* Bottom Level */

.menu li:hover .sub-menu  {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}


.sub-menu {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #000000;
}

.sub-menu li  {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a{
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

/*END OF MENU TOOLBAR*/

#containerPicture {
    width:62%;
    margin-top: -31.7%;
    margin-left: 18.6%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px groove #000;
}

#headerPicture {
    background: yellow;
    height:20%;
}

#container {
    width: 62%;
    margin-top:-0.5%;
    margin-left: 18.6%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px groove #000;
}

#header {
    background: blue;
    height: 50%;
}
```

I would like to state that I have used a drop down menu provided by Seb Kay. His website: http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-dropdown-menu-with-html-css. I only state this as a reference so that he is at least acknowledged for his craftsmanship.

Comment: Look into the CSS docs for @media

Comment: The goal is to keep the dropdown menuin the white space, correct?

Comment: My goal was to keep everything as I set it. When I alter the window size everything moves around and the page becomes a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the vertical margin and padding rules in your css. This is a little counterintuitive but this rules, when defined with percentage, doesn't take as reference the height, but instead they take the width as reference, so all 4 margins are equal. Example:
If you have: margin: 5%, the top and left margin are the same and they don't depend on the height of the conteiner for the top and bottom margins and the with for the right and left.
For padding it is the same.

So, my solution: if you don't really need a percentage layout, I recomend you to **use `ems` for the vertical margins and paddings**. Otherwise, if you need to mantain proportions, you can use vh units. The **`vh` units** are like a percentage that refers not to the height of the parent but the height of the window, so it is great to mantain proportions on a page when you want to avoid scrolling and yet keep percentage.

Comment: Most of the pages I try to get information on ems units refer to font. Is there a certain way I should go about converting my vertical margins to ems?

Comment: Also, how should I start work altering my CSS into ems units?

Comment: An em refers to the inherited size of your font, so it is great to give some space related to the size of the font, as it will increase for fonts with greater size. If it feels strange, you could try vh.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, I was trying a variety of methods using both ems and vh to try to get a nice picture of how each one differently affected my page under different circumstances. You were really helpful Vandervals and I appreciate the information.